# How to make my Wordpress plugin's options support multi languages?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm working on a Wordpress site that supports multiple languages (using Polylang plugin), I installed a plugin to use but figured out that the plugin's options that I need to set in the admin panel don't allow me to insert different values for the different languages I have.

I expected that by specifying the value from the admin bar (the top bar that shows in admin panel) then setting the values, that can be beneficial but it didn't work.

What do I need to change in the plugin (or somewhere else) to support multi-languages in this plugin?

Comment: As long as the plugin is properly using WP Localization functions for their strings you should be able to use Polylangs "String Translations" more here: https://polylang.pro/doc/strings-translation/.

Comment: The plugin options are fields in the admin panel and I can't find them in "String Translations", most probably I need to modify the code to support multi-languages for the fields.

Comment: What plugin is it?

Comment: A plugin that I bought along with a theme, I'm asking about the way to support a plugin to save the options or its values in multiple languages.

Comment: Check with the developer of the plugin, chances are that what you want to do isn't that simple to implement.

Comment: W/o knowing which plugin it is or more about the setup its hard to really give a solid answer.  Like @cabrerahector said you can reach out to the plugin devs for support...

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/cost-calculator-for-wordpress/21709867
Here's the plugin, Cost Calculator.